# Tomcat8 is only serving JSP files, want to configure to have it serve txt files

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I am using AWS elasticbeanstalk tomcat8 that is configured in a way to serve only JSP files but I would also like it to serve files that are txt or any other extension.

Any advice in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is putting in the following servlet-mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The default servlet was defined but this mapping was missing and by putting it in I was able to access any .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to declare the [default servlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html) into your `web.xml` file.

Nevertheless, check first your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` file, because it this servlet is usually included by default there.

Comment: It is there. But I must tell you that there is Spring framework implemented in the webapp as well, could this be the culprit ?

Comment: Hum... And what's the problem when you try to download a .txt resource?

Comment: Basically .. it does seems like some configuration issue that is controlled by the Spring framework, although I am not 100% sure. What happens is that when I put some abc.txt file in the webapps/ROOT folder and try to access the text file from a browser, it redirects to index.jsp file and the content in the JSP file shows up. And what is more surprising is that when I put any JSP file instead of a text or any other file, the JSP file I can easily access and no redirection happens to index.jsp.

Comment: No idea, then. I suggest you add a "spring-web" tag to your question. And posting the web.xml also would help.

Comment: I have figured out the solution, so I will answer my own post with the solution so that it may help others as well. Thanks for your tips and suggestions, much appreciated.

Comment: Good. Congratulations.